# jQuery DataTables autorefresh

Tags: jquery, python, datatables, web2py

I'm updating a row in a data table (http://www.datatables.net/), but **after a successful update the table doesn't refresh.
The change is transferred to the database, but the user still sees the old data**. Is there a way how to enable auto refresh in the makeEditable() function? I am using Web2Py (Python) btw..

My jQuery in view:

```
    $(document).ready( function () {
var oTable = $('#data_table_wrapper').dataTable({
        "sDom": 'R<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip<',
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumn": [
                {},
                {},
                {}
                    ]       
    }).makeEditable({
        sUpdateURL: "update_some_row"
    });
```

});

My controller function:

```
def update_some_row():
    some = db.some(request.vars["id"]) or redirect(URL('error'))
    column = {request.vars["columnName"].lower():request.vars["value"]}
    some.update_record(**column)
    return 'Row has been updated'
```

Is there something like

```
sAutoRefresh: "true"
```

in the makeEditable() function? Thanks for any tips and advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me! I should return the same value from the function that I entered while changing the field. So after changing the controller part to

```
def update_some_row():
    some = db.some(request.vars["id"]) or redirect(URL('error'))
    column = {request.vars["columnName"].lower():request.vars["value"]}
    some.update_record(**column)
    return request.vars["value"]
```

it started working properly.